# django optimizations cache_page vs template.loaders.cached.Loader

Tags: python, django, caching

Testing some Django optimizations and had some unexpected results between [cache_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache://) vs [template cached.Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader).  I expected `cache_page` would have been more performant since it's a direct cache lookup rather than going through the full templating layer. But I must be misunderstanding something fundamental because consistently the cached.Loader produces better results.

My test case:

1. Loading a simple HTML page with several include templates.
2. Using Django 1.10
3. redis as default cache
4. using ab to load test with `n=1000`, `c=20`

Enabled the `cached.Loader` with this in settings.py:

```
'loaders':[('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ]),
]
```

Enabled the `cache_page` with this decorator:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index2.html",{"static_path":static('myapp/')})
```

I comment and turn on each caching strategy independently. Consistently it looks like:

- `loaders.cached.Loader`:   ~90 requests/sec
- `@cache_page`          :   ~60 requests/sec

Any reason why I'm seeing such drastic gains with `cached.Loader` ( about 30% ) over the `cache_page` strategy?